# In SrchRng, If Cell Contains Data, Paste Formula To The Right

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a VBA function in Access to output a spreadsheet. Unfortunately, I'm not finding any resources online that can help with what I would like to do.

My information is output in columns ("A2:AF" & Lrow). "Lrow" defines the last row of the information. "Lrow +1" is where I have a formula totaling everything in each column.

I'd like to search ("C2:AF" & Lrow) for cells that <> "" and paste a formula (Offset 0,1) to divide that cell by the total in "Lrow +1". For example, in my picture, there is data (225.060) in C4. I am trying to paste a formula in D4 to divide C4 by C11 (or Lrow +1 since Lrow changes each time I output a spreadsheet)

Here is the code I have so far, but I'm stuck on the formula part:

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, Cel As Range
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Set SrchRng = wks.Cells("C2:AF" & Lrow)
For Each Cel In SrchRng
     If Cel.Value <> "" Then
          Cel.Offset(0,1).Value = "=Cel.Value/(???)"
```

[image]

Tim Williams suggested I add my entire code because I'm getting an error with the first line of his answer. I get Error5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Private Sub Command19_Click()
'Export to Excel
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset, rs3 As DAO.Recordset, rs4 
As DAO.Recordset
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim SrchRng As Range, Cel As Range
Dim Lrow As Long, Lrow1 As Long

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng, rng1 As Excel.Range

Set db = CurrentDb
Set appExcel = Excel.Application
Set wbk = appExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set wks = wbk.Worksheets(1)
Set rng = wks.Range("A2")

appExcel.Visible = False

cnt = 1

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qry_Comparison_Bulk")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next

Set rs1 = qdf.OpenRecordset()

For Each fld In rs1.Fields
    wks.Cells(1, cnt).Value = fld.Name
    cnt = cnt + 1
Next fld
Call rng.CopyFromRecordset(rs1, 4000, 26)

qdf.Close
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

For Colx = 4 To 26 Step 2
Columns(Colx).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Next

Set SrchRng = wks.Cells("C2:AF" & Lrow)
For Each Cel In SrchRng
If Cel.Value <> "" Then
    Cel.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=" & Cel.Address & "/" & wks.Cells(Lrow +1, Cell.Column).Address
End If
Next

'Identifies the last row and row beneath it

Lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Lrow1 = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Everything below is formatting

With wks.Range("A" & Lrow1, "AF" & Lrow1)
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.ColorIndex = 2
.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
End With

With wks.Range("C2:AE" & Lrow)
.NumberFormat = "0.000"
End With

wks.Cells(Lrow1, "C").Formula = "=SUM(C2:C" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "E").Formula = "=SUM(E2:E" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "G").Formula = "=SUM(G2:G" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "I").Formula = "=SUM(I2:I" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "K").Formula = "=SUM(K2:K" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "M").Formula = "=SUM(M2:M" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "O").Formula = "=SUM(O2:O" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "Q").Formula = "=SUM(Q2:Q" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "S").Formula = "=SUM(S2:S" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "U").Formula = "=SUM(U2:U" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "W").Formula = "=SUM(W2:W" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "Y").Formula = "=SUM(Y2:Y" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "AA").Formula = "=SUM(AA2:AA" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "AC").Formula = "=SUM(AC2:AC" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "AE").Formula = "=SUM(AE2:AE" & Lrow & ")"
wks.Cells(Lrow1, "B").Formula = "TOTAL (MG)"

With wks.Range("A1:AF1")
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.ColorIndex = 2
.Interior.ColorIndex = 16
.NumberFormat = "@"
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

appExcel.Visible = True


End Sub
```

enter code here

Comment: `Set SrchRng = wks.Cells("C2:AF" & Lrow)` should be `Set SrchRng = wks.Range("C2:AF" & Lrow)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Formula` property, and the formula needs to be parseable

Something like this:

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, Cel As Range
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Set SrchRng = wks.Range("C2:AF" & Lrow).Cells 'edit: "Cells()" >> "Range()"
For Each Cel In SrchRng
     If Cel.Value <> "" Then
          Cel.Offset(0,1).Formula = _
              "=" & Cel.Address & "/" & wks.Cells(Lrow +1, Cel.Column).address
```

Comment: I might be missing something. I followed your example and closed with "End if" and "Next" statements but I get Error5: Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: First line. wks.Cells("C2:AF" & Lrow) = <Invalid procedure call or argument>

Comment: That is directly from your original post: I only addressed the part you siad you were having a problem with.  If you're having a problem with other parts then you need to post the rest of your code.

Comment: I use that same line throughout my code with no issues. I'll post the rest of my code. Thanks Tim.

Comment: Should be `wks.Range("C2:AF" & Lrow)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181241/discussion-between-lando-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Ok, sorry the site recommended I do that. I get error1004: 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed I posted my entire code for you to see.I use wks.Cells elsewhere without issue. It's only here.

Comment: You can't use `Cells` like that with a single string argument.

Comment: Then I'm sorry. I'm not sure how to qualify the object. How do I dim the object?

Comment: It took me forever to figure this out, but I finally got it to work by removing the ".Address" from the end of the statement corrected "Cell.Column" to "Cel.Column" I got it working though!